# Difference between GET and PROPFIND in WebDAV

Tags: http, webdav

According to WebDAV specification ([RFC 4918](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html)):

> The semantics of GET are unchanged when applied to a collection, since GET is defined as, "retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is 
>   identified by the Request-URI" [RFC2616].

and PROPFIND

> retrieves properties defined on the resource identified by the Request-URI.

So GET and PROPFIND more or less retrieve the information of a resource. In this sense, is there any major difference between GET and PROPFIND and when should one be used instead of the other.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The very paragraph, you refer to, explains it:

> GET, when applied to a collection, may return the contents of an "index.html" resource, a human-readable view of the contents of the collection, or something else altogether.

I.e. the `GET` behaves as it historically did, to maintain a backward compatibility. It will typically return an "index" page (file `index.html`, `index.php` or similar) or it will automatically render an HTML page with a directory contents (a file list). This means the WebDAV server can run on the same port as HTTP server (= as an extension of the HTTP server), with the existing HTTP requests behaving the same.

While the WebDAV `PROPFIND` request will return an exactly defined, machine-readable, XML document, according to the WebDAV specification.

---

If you are implementing a WebDAV client or server, you are interested in the `PROPFIND` only. A `GET` response does not have a defined format (not even content), so it cannot be parsed by an application.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

WebDAV PROPFIND method is used to retrieve properties of the resource mentioned by the URI.

HTTP GET method can return the produced data and not the source text of resource, in case if it is pointed to a data producing resource. Refer the below text from RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol.

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.  Source - [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)